# Enviar resposta de notificação pelo php

Tags: php, json

Estou precisando enviar uma resposta http 200 com a string 'SUCCESS', mas minha versão php do servidor é 5.2.17!

No meu caso, o webhook envia dados para a captura para um arquivo chamado notificacao.php, eu leio o conteúdo, gravo no banco de dados e preciso enviar uma resposta, mas não sei como fazer isso!

Alguém sabe como fazer isso no php 5.2.17?

Já tentei as seguintes formas sem sucesso:

```
// erro 1
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
echo "SUCCESS";

// erro 2
$httpStatusCode = 200;
$httpStatusMsg  = 'SUCCESS';
$protocol = isset($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']) ? $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] : 'HTTP/1.0';
header($protocol.' '.$httpStatusCode.' '.$httpStatusMsg);

// erro 3
header("200 SUCCESS");
return "200 SUCCESS";

// erro 4
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo 'SUCCESS';
////

// erro 5
header('Content-Type: application/json');
return 'SUCCESS';   
////

//erro 6
header('Content-Type: application/json');
header('SUCCESS');

///erro 7
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$success =json_encode('SUCCESS');
header($success);   

///erro 8
header("HTTP/1.1 200 SUCCESS");
header("Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8");

///erro 9
header("HTTP/1.1 200");
header("Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8");
result 'SUCCESS';

//erro 10
header("Content-Type:application/json;");
header('HTTP/1.0 200 SUCCESS');

//erro 11
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
echo "SUCCESS";
```

Comment: O problema é que você parece não entender a diferença de header e body dentro da estrutura HTTP e não entende a diferença de JSON pra outros formatos

Comment: Ok, Guilherme eu realmente não sei quase nada de html. Então, por favor, você me ensina a fazer em php uma simples resposta a uma requisição json que funcione?

Comment: Se tiver um tempo na segunda eu explico  o que é json, html e http

Comment: Tá "serto", não sabe a resposta e ainda vem querer humilhar os outros? Lamentável!!!! Se você soubesse a resposta postaria aqui....

Comment: Amigo você esta equivocado e a sua atitude é totalmente desrespeitosa, sugiro que procure se comportar ou terei que reportar a situação, ok estou no meio de um trabalho tentando terminar pra aproveitar o pouco tempo que tenho no fim de semana mas vou responder. Agora se tornar a ter este tipo de situação infelizmente terei que reportar. Entendeu? Aguarde estou providenciando uma resposta para a sua duvida. Enquanto isso **LEIA**: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice se não ler realmente será **lamentável!**

Comment: @prmas evita julgamentos rápidos. Estamos todos aqui para partilhar soluções e conhecimento sobre programação. Acabaste por receber uma resposta bem boa do Guilherme.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

O Código 200 é o padrão se não ocorreu nenhum problema na requisição, então isso deve bastar:

```
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
echo "SUCCESS";
```

Comment: Eu editei e inseri as formas que já tentei sem sucesso!!!

Comment: Julio, minha solução foi: header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK'); echo 'SUCCESS'; return; Obrigado por sua contribuição!!!

Comment: @prmas engraçado que na resposta do Julio não tem nada sobre o "200 OK" e na minha resposta tem. Recomendo que revise o seu comportamento na comunidade e sempre presuma boa intenção dos demais usuários, mesmo que um comentário soar estranho.

Comment: Guilherme, eu fiz a mesma pergunta em inglês no post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37502915/send-response-http-200-success-in-php?noredirect=1#comment62518020_37502915 e a resposta que me ajudou foi a do usuário Shadi Shaaban! Eu já havia dado os pontos para o Julio Neto e achei por bem continuar com a mesma ética. Obrigado por sua resposta, mas ela veio depois da citada acima. Desculpe se eu te desrespeitei, mas o que eu senti após sua segunda resposta não foi nada bom. Quando o problema é urgente não há como esperar até segunda ou terça ainda que a ajuda voluntária. Abraço!!!

Comment: @prmas isso não faz sentido algum, a resposta que deve ser escolhida nada deve ter haver com cronologia, a questão é que você levou a mal um comentário que você interpretou mal, se foi uma resposta do Stackoverflow em ingles que lhe resolveu o problema é lá e não aqui, então você deveria ter formalizado uma resposta correta para o problema que é o `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`, como eu já tinha respondido o caminho correto então seria recomendavel você escolher ela, mas isto esta claro que é uma situação de má vontade e falta de reconhecimento...

Comment: @prmas ... realmente ou você não entende o funcionamento de um Q&A ou você esta chateado por ter entendido mal o meu comentário. A pergunta e resposta escolhidas devem servir pra você e para futuros usuários, fazer uma escolha de uma resposta que não resolve o problema por um motivo qualquer é totalmente prejudicial para o site.

Answer (score 8):

O problema é que você não entende a diferença de JSON e HTML ou TEXTO, isso é o minimo que tem que estudar antes de tentar usar estes formatos.

Isso `echo "SUCCESS";` imprime isto na resposta da requisição `SUCCESS`, isto não é JSON, o JSON tem um formato como:

```
{ "response": "SUCCESS" }
```

E o cabeçalho (header) deve ser UTF-8 (claro que pode usar outros tipos de charset, mas o padrão e recomendado é o UTF-8 para este caso) quando usar json, então o PHP deve ficar assim:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
echo json_encode(array( 'response' => 'SUCCESS' ));
```

A função `json_encode` não transforma magicamente strings em JSON, ele apenas converte strings em um formato aceito dentro de valores no JSON, ou seja:

- Quotes (`"`) em `\"`
- E acentos tipo `ã` em `\u00e3`

Agora se usar em um array como fiz no exemplo irá funcionar.

Pelo seus usos do `header` como `header("200 SUCCESS");` nota-se também que não entendeu ou ainda não entende bem como funciona o HTTP.

> HTTP é sigla de HyperText Transfer Protocol que em português significa "Protocolo de Transferência de Hipertexto". É um protocolo de comunicação entre sistemas de informação que permite a transferência de dados entre redes de computadores, principalmente na World Wide Web (Internet).

Ele se comunica através de **Requisição** e **Resposta**, ou seja o cliente (pode ser um navegador ou outro servidor) faz uma *requisição* para um servidor e este servidor devolve uma *resposta*.

Tanto **Requisição** quanto **Resposta** geralmente são compostos de cabeçalho e corpo, exceto Requisições GET e HEAD, ou respostas para requisições HEAD (tem mais tipos de requisições mas não é o foco citar elas ainda).

Um exemplo de requisição que o cliente faz para um servidor:

Cabeçalho:

```
GET /questions/130929/enviar-resposta-de-notificação-pelo-php HTTP/1.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Connection: keep-alive
Host: pt.stacokverflow.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Identificação do navegador)
```

> No caso de GET não tem "corpo"

E que o servidor envia para resposta acima pode ser algo semelhante a isto:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Sat, 28 May 2016 22:03:54 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 17736
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding

<html>
...
</html>
```

Veja que o cabeçalho vai do HTTP/1.0 (ou 1.1) até a quebra de linha que vem após o `Vary: Accept-Encoding` e o corpo vem após esta quebra de linha, aonde começa o `<html>` (claro que podem haver outras quebras de linha ou outro tipo de conteúdo, mas ainda sim seria o CORPO).

Um escopo básico de como funciona a requisição e resposta no HTTP:

> [image: http]

Usando no PHP, a função 'header' no PHP sempre deve vir antes de `echo`, `print`, `var_dump` ou qualquer conteúdo que vai pra "saida" no corpo da resposta do HTTP (exceto se usar `ob_start`), nunca depois, se não isto causará falha, ou se os erros estiverem desligados isto causará apenas o envio de parte da resposta e os cabeçalhos padrões do servidor serão enviados ao invés do seu.

Quase todos seus testes estão totalmente errados,

1. Não existe "header" ou "verb" chamado `200 SUCCESS`:

   ```
   //erro 3
   header("200 SUCCESS");
   return "200 SUCCESS";
   ```
2. `return` não é a mesma coisa que echo e não serve pra enviar conteudo pra resposta:

   ```
   //erro 5
   header('Content-Type: application/json');
   return 'SUCCESS';
   ```
3. Não existe "header" ou "verb" chamado `SUCCESS`:

   ```
   //erro 6
   header('Content-Type: application/json');
   header('SUCCESS');
   ```
4. Além do primeiro header está faltando uma parte a função `result` não existe:

   ```
   ///erro 9
   header("HTTP/1.1 200");
   header("Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8");
   result 'SUCCESS';
   ```
5. Não se passa dados do "corpo" no "header":

   ```
   ///erro 7
   header('Content-Type: application/json');
   $success =json_encode('SUCCESS');
   header($success);
   ```
6. Estes estão quase corretos, mas faltou o "corpo" e não existe header ou verb assim `HTTP/1.1 200 SUCCESS`

   ```
   ///erro 8
   header("HTTP/1.1 200 SUCCESS");
   header("Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8");
   ```

   E neste:

   ```
   //erro 10
   header("Content-Type:application/json;");
   header('HTTP/1.0 200 SUCCESS');
   ```

No HTTP como eu disse o 200 é padrão, mas se você tiver um outro header que tenha afetado o padrão então você pode usar a função header assim:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8", false, 200);
```

Todavia se quiser alterar apenas o código de status então o correto seria isto:

```
$protocol = isset($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']) ? $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] : 'HTTP/1.0';
header($protocol.' 200 OK');
```

Ou no PHP5.4:

```
http_response_code(200);
```

Resumido o correto é `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` para o status 200, se quiser outros códigos de status veja os links a seguir.

### Lista de códigos HTTP

A teu problema não é bem o HTTP, mas ainda sim é bom aprender quais são os códigos de status corretos, segue dois links para estudar:

- https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

### Aonde esta o problema então?

Sobre o seu problema, de enviar a resposta 200, ela já é padrão no servidor, o que deve estar ocorrendo é que você esta usando jQuery, como `$.ajax` ou `$.get` ou `$.post` e a resposta esta sim vindo como 200, mas o json esta em um formato invalido (como eu citei no começo da resposta), isto faz o *"PARSE"* do jQuery falhar, então sempre ocorre o erro.

Então o seu PHP deve ficar assim:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');

//Funções MYSQL

echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Claro que se quiser enviar um código de status em caso de erro no PHP pode tentar usar o `ob_start`, assim podera usar a função header depois de `echo`, ficaria assim:

```
<?php
ob_start();
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');

if (... EXECUTA A QUERY MYSQL ...) {
    $resposta = 'success';
} else {
    $resposta = 'error';
}

echo json_encode(array( 'response' => $resposta ));
```

E o Jquery deve ser algo assim:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: '[SUA PÁGINA PHP].php',
  data: { "DADOS DO POST": "VALOR A SER ENVIADO" },
  dataType: "json" //IMPORTANTE
}).done(function(data) {
    alert(data.response);//response é o mesmo que foi enviado no json_encode
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert( "error:" + textStatus );
});
```

### Documentação

Evite dar "tiro no escuro", recomendo que olhe sempre a documentação antes de usar uma função, segue os links pra documentação pra estudar:

- [header do php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)
- [return do php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php)
- [echo do php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php)
- [ob_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php)
- [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/index.php)
- [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com)
- [json](http://www.json.org)
- [Protocolos (HTTP)](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/)

Comment: +1 pelo capricho na resposta e por não se deixar levar pela falta de respeito do autor da pergunta.